# Weird caching behavior "Provisional headers are shown" in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-devtools, google-console-developer

Can anyway explain the results in Chrome of the tests below? It doesn't look logical to me.

TEST.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    Test caching behavior ...
</body>
</html>
```

I'm aware of the fact that extensions in Chrome can have influence on: "Provisional headers are shown". So for this test first i've disabled all my extensions in Chrome.

Now i did the following:

- Step 1:
  Type in addressbar and press enter: http://www.example.com/test.html (to be sure i pressed also CONTROL F5)
  The result is:
  Status Code: 200 OK
  Size: 510 B
- Step 2:
  Now i pressed: CONTROL N (opening new window).
  Before i'm typing something in the addressbar i went to "Developer Tools" > "Network" tab
  Now i typed in addressbar and pressed enter: http://www.example.com/test.html
  Now the result is:
  Status Code: 200 OK
  Size: 183 B

So the size is less, so i thought maybe there is some caching going on. But the status code is "200 OK" and not:

"200 OK (from disk cache)"
or 
"200 OK (from memory cache)"

Now i wanted to test if Chrome made a request in step 2, so i changed the file:

"Test caching behavior ..." 
i chacnged to: 
"Test caching behavior ... (2)"

Now i repeated "step 2". The browser was not showing "(2)", so that means Chrome is taking the file from cache.
In the developer Tool i saw also:

> Request Headers: Provisional headers are shown

So Chrome is taking the file from cache, but is showing "200 OK" (green) without any caching signs like "(from disk cache)" or "(from memory cache)".
This doesn't seem logical to me. Why Chrome is doing that?